# UIImageView.image setter

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have two side view made this way:
containerView - container of both views
firstView - visible view which is made of UIImageView
secondView - view visible after flipping

Now I'm downloading image async to present on firstView using SDWebImage library with method:

```
    [view.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.image]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Image can be horizontal or vertical.
Now I want secondView to be the same size as presented image. I was thinking of setting it in UIImageView custom setter but I don't know how to get that method.
Maybe any other ideas?

edit:

Image[image]

I think I know how to do it. What I just need now is actual VISIBLE size of UIImageView.image.

Comment: Perhaps some pictures would help? I have no idea what you're actually asking here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to import `AVFoundation` to your project these is a convenience function `AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect` which takes an image size and image view frame and gives you the size at which the image will be displayed.

You can obviously write some code yourself to calculate the same values using a little maths.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `property` for the image that is being downloaded. Then create a custom `setter` for this `property` - in here update your `secondImageView` size.

This way, each time the `imageBeingDownloaded` has finished downloading - it will set the image - which will then update the `secondImageView size`

i.e.

In the implementation file

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImage *imageBeingDownloaded; // creates the property

// The custom setter
- (void)setImageBeingDownloaded:(UIImage *)imageBeingDownloaded {
    _imageBeingDownloaded = imageBeingDownloaded;
    self.secondImageView.size = _imageBeingDownloaded.size; // each time the image is set this will update secondImageView
}
```

Then

`[view.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.image]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];`

becomes

`[self.imageBeingDownloaded setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.image]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];`